# mount(Component).debug() is giving emtpy value

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I tried to implement `mount` from `enzyme` in the following but found `wrapper.debug()` is empty.

```
import {mount} from 'enzyme';
const Foo = () => <div>Sairam</div>;

describe(...
   it(...
      const wrapper = mount(<Foo/>);
      console.log(wrapper.debug()) // gives empty value
```

UPDATE:

```
import { 
  specs, describe, it, 
  beforeEach, before, after, afterEach, xdescribe
} from 'storybook-addon-specifications';

import {mount, shallow} from 'enzyme';

storiesOf('UI|Components', module)
  .add('with text', () => {
    const Foo = () => <div>Sairam</div>;
    specs(() =>
      describe('with text', () => {
        it('Clicking on the showFirst button should select the first page', () => {
          const wrapper = mount(<Foo/>);
          console.log("WRAPPER TEST" , wrapper.debug());
          // expect(wrapper.props().chipData).to.equal(ChipData);
          wrapper.unmount();
          expect(2).toBe(23);
        });
      })
    );
    return story;
  })
```

Comment: hmm...I can't recreate this issue.  What version of `enzyme`, `jest`, and `react`?

Comment: enzyme@3.9.0
 jest@23.6.0

Comment: react@16.8.4  are the versions

Comment: Add some details, maybe test project on github. What is the console output? Have you tried to `console.log('test')` beside of that `debug`? Is it visible in the console?

Comment: Also, at least, add complete minimum example file, without `...` or something like that.

Comment: @extempl Please check now .

Comment: So it is not working for you in storybooks. Does it works without and manual launching certain test file? Like you wrote in first code, just `describe`?

Comment: it was a issue with decorator

Comment: once I removed it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Reason why it is failed for me is because of adding decorator

`addDecorator(StoryRouter());` to my `.storybookconfig` file